# minimal number of privileged instructions?

Tags: operating-system

minimal number of privileged instructions?
Say we want to write a OS with minimal number of privileged instruction.

I think it should be 1, only MMU register. But what about other things? i.e mode bit, trap

Answer (score 0):

Operating System need to provide security (including memory isolation from different programs) and abstraction (each program doesn't need to care how much memory is available on physical memory). 
To maintain these: you need at least 1 privileged instruction.

The privilege instruction is to setup Memory Management Unit registers so that you can ensure the memory is protected. There should be no IO instructions and all IO and interrupt access should be memory mapped.

Use MMU to ensure kernel memory, kernel code, "memory of interrupt access" and "device's memory mapped IO interface" are not mapped to user space, so user processes cannot access these. These memories lies in kernel memory.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can implement an operating system with everything in system mode, and you could argue that there are no "privileged" instructions.

---

As to whether you could implement an OS with privileged and non-privileged modes using N different privileged instructions:

- it would depend on the functionality you aimed to implement,
- it would depend on the hardware instruction set, MMU design, etcetera, and
- unless you were prepared to put months / years into a theoretical analysis, it would be a matter of debate / opinion as to whether your proposed answer was indeed correct.